# PHP : got a json parse error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I want to import data from the database into my javascript code, using ajax through jQuery, but I got a json parse error and I really don't know what it does come from. Could you help me ?

The goal is to build buildings on a map, and i take the geometry elements such as coordinates and shape parameters from the database.

in the JS file,  put:

> ```
>  $.ajax({ 
>
>   type: "GET",
>   url: "ajax_processor.php",
>   dataType : "html",
>
>   error:function(msg, string){ 
>      alert( "Error !: " + string );
>   }
>
>   success:function(returnData){ 
>
>      var data = $.parseJSON(returnData); 
>
>      for(var ID_geometryElement  in data) {
>           addComp($data[bldg], 
>                   $data[iZ], // zone where is the building
>                   $data[iType], //type of the geometric element
>                   $data[x0],
>                   $data[y0],//coordinates top-left
>                   $data[p], // geometric parameters
>                   );
>      }
>    }
>  });
> ```
>
> });

in the PHP file:

> ```
> try {
>    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=building_geometry','admin','password');
> }
>
>  $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM ID_GEOMETRYELEMENT');
>  $donnees = $reponse->fetch(); 
>
>   header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
>   echo json_encode($response); 
>
>   ?>
> ```

Comment: What are you getting back from the ajax?

Comment: First of all you have to fix one thing in JS code. If you're writing `for(var ID_geometryElement  in data) {` then you getting each item in `ID_geometryElement` variable, not in `$data` (and from where you get $ sign in JS var?).

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I want the ajax to execute the function addComp() and to fill the data with those it queried from the database, but I got an error before, in the json parsing.

Comment: Is your php program outputting anything else other than the output of a single call to `json_encode()`? What does the browser show in the http response data? Also, in your JS code, you appear to have a variable named `data`, but it looks like you're referring to it by the name `$data`. That looks like a bug.

Comment: you have a try without a catch....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to json_encode the database statement handle your query returned. That is NOT something you can encode. The code should be

```
echo json_encode($donnees);
                 ^^^^^^^^--- the actual data
```

If you'd done even the most basic debugging, e.g. `console.log(returnData)` in JS, you'd have seen you're not getting anything valid returned from the script.

Comment: Since that's my very first time in coding in javascript, i didn't know there was this debug tool. I'll try that, thanks !

Comment: Thanks, that works now using Firebug, I got the json parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType : "html",
```

must be

```
dataType : "json",
```

if you expect JSON in the response

**EDIT:** See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

> dataType
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

Comment: that does nothing. datatype json tells jquery you're EXPECTING json back from the server, causing it to decode the string automatically. but OP's doing .parseJSON anyways, so type:html is 'ok'.

Comment: Oh yeah, I already changed that, but I have still the error in json parse

Answer (score 0):

$response is just a cursor, you need to return the fetched data.

```
try {
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=building_geometry','admin','password');
}

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM ID_GEOMETRYELEMENT');
$donnees = $reponse->fetch(); 

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode($donnees);
```

?>